# ¿Cómo solucionar problemas al editar en laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo un formulario en láravel el cual me permite hacer registro de productos y insetar la imagen, tengo un problema al momento de editar, ya que habra veces que solo quiera editar la información y no la imagen, al hacer eso me genera el error, quisiera saber como solucionarlo,
Este es el código de la vista:

```
 <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
          <label>Agregar IMAGEN</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend bg-transparent">
              </div>
            <input type="file"  value="{{ $item->img1_producto }}"  class="form-control" name="file"  accept="image/*"></div></div>
```

Este es el de mi controlador:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id_producto)
    {
        $nombre_a_guardar = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $DatosProd->nombre_producto = $request->nameProd;    
        $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/imagenes', $nombre_a_guardar);
        $DatosProd->img1_producto = $nombre_a_guardar;
        $DatosProd->save();
```

Comment: Comprueba si la imagen existe antes de intentar trabajar con ella. Las comprobaciones son el 90% del código a la hora de programar, nunca racanees con ellas. Compruébalo todo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes determinar si un archivo está presente en la solicitud utilizando el método `hasFile`. Por lo que poniendo dentro de un condicional la lógica que usas para el manejo del archivo, tu problema se resolvería:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id_producto)
{
    //...
    $DatosProd->nombre_producto = $request->nameProd;  
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $nombre_a_guardar = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();  
        $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/imagenes', $nombre_a_guardar);
        $DatosProd->img1_producto = $nombre_a_guardar;
    }
    $DatosProd->save();
    //...
```

Referencia: [HTTP Requests: Files](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#files).